# Rotation of a line by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Give the equation of the line $\ell'$ that is obtained by rotating $\ell$: $x+2y=5$ by an angle of $\theta=\frac{1}{2}\pi$ with center point $O(0,0)$.

The rotation matrix is $\left.\begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{pmatrix}\right|_{\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\pi}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Two points on $\ell$ are $(1,2)$ and $(3,1)$, whose images are respectively $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\end{pmatrix}$.
Hence, the gradient of $\ell'$ is $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=2$. Therefore, the equation of $\ell'$ is $y=2(x+2)+1\iff \boxed{y=2x+5}$.

---

I have two questions: my book says the answer should be $y=2x+6$. If I am wrong, what did I wrong? Second, is there anyone who suggests a more elegant of faster method for this problem?

Comment: I guess you could know the gradient is $2$, because the lines are orthogonal so the gradient multiplication is $-1$ . Now you can take $(0,2.5)$ and it will rotate to $(-2.5,0)$. so you have point and gradient

Comment: Sorry for asking, but could not understand that none of the two answer vindicates the book's answer as correct. So, can I construe the book to be wrong.

Comment: @jiten this question is literally 3 years old hahaha

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the point $(1,2)$ is on the original line. After a rotation by $\pi/2$, this point becomes $(-2,1)$. I also notice that the original slope was $-1/2$. A rotation by $\pi/2$ has the effect of finding a line perpendicular to our starting line, so it will have slope $2$.

The equation of a line with slope $2$ passing through $(-2,1)$ is $y - 1 = 2(x + 2)$, or rather $y = 2x + 5$.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but $(1,1)$ is not on the original line..

Comment: @CauchytheDog well, you're right. Thank you. It turns out that $2 \cdot 1 = 2 \neq 4$. It's an amusing coincidence it gives the correct answer that way too.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way:

Given line is $x+2y=5$, so we could say $x=r$ and $y=\dfrac{5-r}{2}$.

Now we multiply $\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} r\\ \dfrac{5-r}{2}\\ \end{pmatrix}$, it gives us coordinates after rotation which are
$\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{r-5}{2}\\ r\\ \end{pmatrix}$. namely, the new $x=\dfrac{r-5}{2}$ and the new $y=r$, so the line after rotation is $y=2x+5$